# MAPI vs IMAP vs POP3

Tags: c#, c++, mapi

We have supported different options in our product to download emails including IMAP and POP3.  Providing IMAP and POP3 support was very simple as there is lot of documentation and .Net libraries available.  Now we need to support MAPI.
    I am having trouble with finding good library in .Net, I found one called `NetMAPI` but couldn't find examples.  Also I am not able to understand how we specify connection properties.  e.g. IMAP we have different properties like email address, password, port , SSL enabled etc.  Below are few questions.

1. Where do I mention these connection parameters when it comes to
   MAPI? ( creating profile? )
2. Some example says we have to mention profile name.  Does that means I have to have outlook installed and create profile using outlook?

I am looking at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2048/Simple-MAPI-NET) example but not sure how below Logon method is working on my machine.

```
[DllImport( "MAPI32.DLL", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int MAPILogon(IntPtr hwnd, string prf, string pw, int flg, int rsv, ref IntPtr sess );

public bool Logon( IntPtr hwnd )
{
    winhandle = hwnd;
    error = MAPILogon( hwnd, null, null, 0, 0, ref session );
    if( error != 0 )
        error = MAPILogon( hwnd, null, null, MapiLogonUI, 0, ref session );
    return error == 0;
}
```

I am able to connect to my mailbox which is configured in outlook but don't know from where its picking up my mailbox details.  I tried entering random ( invalid ) values for `prf` and `pw` fields still I am able to connect to my mailbox.
Strange but true.
Can someone please refer me to some good documentation to understand how to use MAPI ( preferably using managed API? ) 
Thanks

Comment: MAPI is a proprietary protocol/API used only in Microsoft Windows, while IMAP and POP3 are Internet standards. This explains the difference in freely available documentation, that you've observed. You should be able to find all the documentation about MAPI that you need by purchasing appropriate Microsoft documentation.

Comment: No need to purchase anything - there is a ton of low-level information about MAPI freely available on MSDN.